# Why jq does not see environment variables when run in script?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
"1":
 {
   "media_content":"test3.xspf"
 },
"2":
 {
   "media_content":"test3.xspf"
 }
}
```

In the terminal, using bash as shell, I can execute the following commands:

```
export schedules="1"
echo $(jq '.[env.schedules]["media_content"]' json_file.json)
```

Which results in outputing this:

```
test3.xspf
```

So it works as expected, but when I place that jq command in a script and run it, it just returns null.
I did echo the values of schedules to make sure the value is non-null inside the script, and it is ok:

```
echo $schedules
```

But I did not manage to find the reason, why this command works when run directly in shell and does not work when run in script.

I run the script in the following ways:

```
bash script.sh
./script.sh
```

PS: yes, I did offer execute permission:  `chmod +x script.sh`

HINT: `env.schedules` represents the environment variable 'schedules', and I did make sure that it is assigned in the script before calling `jq`.

EDIT: I am posting now a whole script, specifying the files tree.

There is one directory containing:

- script.sh
- json_file.json
- static.json

script.sh:

```
export zone=$(cat static.json | jq '.["1"]');

echo "json block: "$zone

export schedules="$(echo $zone | jq '.schedules')"

echo "environment variable: "$schedules
export media_content=$(jq '.[env.schedules]["media_content"]' json_file.json)

echo "What I want to get: \"test3.xspf\""
echo "What I get: "$media_content
```

json_file.json:

```
{
"1":
 {
   "media_content":"test3.xspf"
 },
"2":
 {
   "media_content":"test3.xspf"
 }
}
```

static.json:

```
{
"1":
 {
   "x": "0",
   "y": "0",
   "width": "960",
   "height": "540",
   "schedules":"1"
 }
}
```

If I run the script, it displays:

```
json block: { "x": "0", "y": "0", "width": "960", "height": "540", "schedules": "1" }
environment variable: "1"
What I want to get: "test3.xspf"
What I get: null
```

If I hardcode the variable:

```
export schedules="1"
```

The problem no longer occurs

Comment: Can you post the script? How are you running it?

Comment: I updated:   
bash script.sh  or:
./script.sh  
 
The script consists in the two lines which use jq.

Comment: `echo $(..)` is a useless use of echo. It's like `echo $(echo $(echo $(...))))`. Just type `jq`, no need for echo.

Comment: @Alexandru-MihaiManolescu According to what you posted, your code should work. Please post the exact script, with its content.

Comment: @Maroun thank you. I removed all redundant parts and kept those two lines (the whole software contains about 9 long shell scripts and posting everything would  bring more confusion). I reconsider posting more but I don't think those parts are related :(( Thank you  again

Comment: @Maroun I updated the question with a whole script that reproduces the error, if you run it. I also pasted the content of the json files. I found that the problem no longer occurs if I set schedules="1"

Comment: @Alexandru-MihaiManolescu So I guess you know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple.
It's not jq's fault.
It the unproper way the schedule's value is piped to the next command.

You have to remove the "s that surround the variable's value, add the second command that uses sed to do that:

```
    export schedules="$(echo $zone | jq '.schedules')"
    schedules=$( echo $schedules | sed s/\"//g )
```

**Long answer**
Let's see:
here schedules is a string and echo shows its value as being 1:

```
export schedules="1" ; echo $schedules
```

here even though double quotes are not mentioned:

```
export schedules=1 ; echo $schedules
```

But the result from this also generates additional "s:

```
export schedules=$(echo $zone | jq '.schedules')
```

If you print it now you will see additional "s:

```
echo $schedules # "1"
```

So just remove the "s from the value:

```
schedules=$( echo $schedules | sed s/\"//g )
```

Comment: It's not a "pseudo-string", it's a string, period. *All* values in shell are strings; the quotes are about escaping characters with special meaning, not specifying a data type. A better solution, though, would be to have `jq` output a raw string rather than a quoted JSON string using `export schedules=$(echo "$zone" | jq -r '.schedules')`.